# No python virtualenv is available error when running nodeenv -p

Tags: python, node.js, virtualenv, nodeenv

I have installed nodeenv for node.js and virtualenv for python and would like to link both by using the command nodeenv -p in virtualenv.

I get this error No python virtualenv is available.

any ideas what my be missing. the virtualenv has it all and i having running django in it.

I tried to install and reinstall but it did not work.

I am using MAC OS SONOMA

Comment: What exactly did you do; what exacty did you expect, and why? See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].